# getting Error called " Build failed. " in my parcel project

Tags: javascript, parcel

I m trying to use parcel to build my project but i am getting that error here are the my package.json and the picture of er

```
{
  "name": "starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "script.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "author": "Jonas",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^1.12.4"
  }
}
```

and this is my error

[image]

Comment: what is your folder structure? it might be `main: index.html`